# Countdown timer in Javascript mm:ss format with restricted text input

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I finished countdown timer but I ran into few issues which i'd like to solve. I couldn't find any solution for my problem. In here on Stackoverflow nor Youtube.

Timer input doesn't take alphabet or special characters.
Doesn't go to negative numbers or even negative numbers can't be pasted in the input.

Issues i ran into and can't solve: Timer input only takes seconds

What I'm trying to achieve: Make input to take mm:ss format and able user to edit it by needs.

Possible options I was thinking about: Only possible option I see as working one is to make two different "ghost" inputs. Where user will type his values for example: textInput-1 (minutes) 8 textInput-2 (seconds) 23. result: 8:23. Which will be sent and shown on a timer.

I'm definitely sure what I'm trying to achieve it's possible but I probably missing something.

Thank you for any help or advice.Have a nice day ! :-)

Martin.

Comment: Can you share your code please, nobody going to write it down from beginning.

Comment: and yet there must be more than a thousand time pickers on github ...

Comment: Cem, thank you for your answer. As I mentioned on the first sentence of the post I finished it. I'm asking for advice about mm:ss input because I can't find solution for that anywhere.

Comment: Mister Jojo thank you for your answer, I finished timer only problem is that input takes only second and not mm:as format

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear - maybe some codes will help.
Basically whatever control you want (that doesn't exist) can be quickly built.
You can quickly build a time input with any control you want.
This is just an idea of what can be built. It's custom and you can manipulate whatever control you want

```
<style type='text/css'>
.custom-timer{
  display:flex;
  background-color:white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.custom-timer .input{
  border:0;
  width:32px;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.custom-timer .separator{
  margin:0 7px;
}

.custom-timer .separator::before{
  content: ":"
}
</style>

<div class='custom-timer'><input type='text' class='min input'><span 
class='separator'></span><input type='text' class='sec input'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function countDown(){
      let sec=document.querySelector(".custom-timer .sec"), 
 min=document.querySelector(".custom-timer .sec");
 let sec_val= sec.value, min_val=min.value;
 sec_val--;
 if(sec_val <0){
   sec_val=60;
   min_val--;
 }
 sec.value= sec_val;
 min.value= min_val
   }
</script>
```

The script added is in response to your last question in the comment

Comment: Hello Kjut, Thank you very much for your answer. 

You understood the question perfectly. Thank you for added CSS as well. Very nice of you ! :) 

I'll try your answer to use "two different input" 

But I have a question do you think it will be able to behave as timer ? 

What I mean by that. Will i be able make every 60 seconds substract 1 minute ?

Thank you I'll send here my code if you're able to cope with me for a bit.

Comment: Yes of course - you have all the controls you want
For instance:
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>